# Error : "The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted."

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i was click the button for export pdf so there is an error on my webpage 
"The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted." and also this error 
[No relevant source lines]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MPHome.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CancelledInvoiceListRpt.aspx.cs" Inherits="CancelledInvoiceListRpt" %>
```

this is the top of aspx page.. how to fix this please help me....

Answer (score 0):

set `EnableEventValidation="false" ViewStateEncryptionMode="Never"` in page directive.